# Error: expression 'readLine(stdin)' is of type 'TaintedString' and has to be discarded

Tags: compiler-errors, nim-lang

Nim compiler error:

```sh
Error: expression 'readLine(stdin)' is of type 'TaintedString' and has to be discarded
```

Source code:

```py
var i = 1
for i in countup(1, 100000000):
  var line: string = readLine(stdin)
```

error in line 3

Answer (score 3):

That is not the source code that caused the error. The code you show compiles and runs correctly. But you don't need to declare `i` before the loop. This two lines would work:

```
for i in countup(1, 100000000):
  var line: string = readLine(stdin)
```

The code that causes the error you menction is this:

```
for i in countup(1, 100000000):
  readLine(stdin)
```